# Lightbox imageDataContainer at the bottom disappears after image has loaded

Tags: css, lightbox2

Hello and thanks for helping,
I have made some lightboxes and they are working perfectly except for 2 little problems:

1. In all browsers, the white section at the bottom of the images where the close button is located disappears as soon as the image loads.
2. In IE, the word "null" is above the image number, also located at the bottom of the image.
   Click on any image on this page for an example:
   http://www.furniturebymartin.co.uk/casestudy3.html

I have tried changing everything I could find in the CSS file, especially to do with the imageDataContainer tag... but no luck. Any ideas? Thanks very much.

MY CSS CODE:

```
#lightbox{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;
text-align: center;
line-height: 0;
}

#lightbox a img{ border: none; }

#outerImageContainer{
position: relative;
background-color: #fff;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#imageContainer{
padding: 10px;
}

#loading{
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
left: 0%;
height: 25%;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 0;
}
#hoverNav{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;
}
#imageContainer>#hoverNav{ left: 0;}
#hoverNav a{ outline: none;}

#prevLink, #nextLink{
width: 49%;
height: 100%;
background: transparent url(../images/blank.gif) no-repeat; /* Trick IE into showing hover */
display: block;
}
#prevLink { left: 0; float: left; background: url(../images/prevlabel.gif) left 0% no-repeat; }
#nextLink { right: 0; float: right; background: url(../images/nextlabel.gif) right 0% no-repeat; }
#prevLink:hover, #prevLink:visited:hover { background: url(../images/prevlabel.gif) left 0% no-repeat; }
#nextLink:hover, #nextLink:visited:hover { background: url(../images/nextlabel.gif) right 0% no-repeat; }

#imageDataContainer{
font: 10px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: #fff;
margin: 0 auto;
line-height: 1.4em;
display: block
class: clearfix
}

#imageData{ padding:0 10px; color: #666; }
#imageData #imageDetails{ width: 70%; float: left; text-align: left; }  
#imageData #caption{ font-weight: bold; }
#imageData #numberDisplay{ display: block; clear: left; padding-bottom: 1.0em;  }           
#imageData #bottomNavClose{ width: 66px; float: right;  padding-bottom: 0.7em;  }   

#overlay{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 90;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color: #000;
}


/* Min-Width */
.lbWidth { /* most browsers */
position: absolute;
top: 0px; left: 0px;
width: 100%;
min-width: 790px;
}

* html .lbContent { /* IE6 */
margin-left: -790px;
position:relative;
}

* html .lbMinWidth { /* IE6 */
padding-left: 790px;
}

.lightBox({ fixedNavigation: true });

/* Clearfix */  
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;}

.clearfix {display: inline-block;}

/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually solved it myself!

In case you are interested,this bit of code close to the bottom:

```
.lightBox({ fixedNavigation: true });
```

...was getting in the way of the white bar where close is located. I had added that bit of code because my next and prev buttons were flying into place and it was really odd and distracting.

So I gave up and just downloaded the latest version of Lightbox2 I could find:

http://www.richandstephsipe.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/lightboxcss.txt

...and renamed it so that it is now a CSS file that my pages link to. That sorted it out a treat!